# Как увеличить область при которой будет срабатывать клик?

Tags: java, android, button, android-button

Есть кнопка, она не очень большого размера, как можно увеличить область по которой будет срабатывать клик, не используя при этом padding и не увеличивая саму кнопку ?

**SocerActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBlack"
tools:context=".SocerActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/team_name_2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fragment3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fragment3" />

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_refresh"
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_arrow"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/text_vs"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fragment3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fragment"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/text_back"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_exit_scoreboard"
    android:text="@string/text_back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/fols"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/team_name_1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fragment"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fragment" />

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_start"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/digital7momo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"

    android:textSize="70sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/digital7"
    android:text="@string/numberOfTime_t1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/refresh"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.tabelkomo.ScoreboardFragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/scoreboard_fragment_one" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment6"
    android:name="com.example.tabelkomo.ScoreboardFragmentFols"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/scoreboard_fols_fragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:name="com.example.tabelkomo.ScoreboardFragmentTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/scoreboard_fragment_two" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Есть ImageButton с id="refresh", если использую padding картинка уменьшается

Comment: поместить кнопку в другую вьюшку или контейнер и повесить на эту вьюшку слушатель.

Comment: @UjinUkr не могли бы Вы навести пример в коде?

Comment: а чем паддинги не подходят?

Comment: @pavlofff из-за того что ImageButton картинка стает очень маленькая

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у Вас, отведено ограниченное место для кнопки. Но Вы все же хотите чтобы клик  производился и за границами этой кнопки, тобишь на територии другого элемента экрана?

Comment: Если картинка становится очень маленькой, значит придется пожертвовать драгоценным местом и увеличить контейнер в котором Ваша кнопка лежит до размера зоны желаемого клика. Вместо того что бы уменьшать размер кнопки применяя паддинг в фиксированном контейнере.

Comment: Но эти все советы будут безполезны. Более того, Ваш вопрос породит кучу советов общего характера пока Вы не покажете разметку. И не укажете конкретно что Вы пытались сделать и что у Вас не получилось.

Comment: @V.March у меня обычный ConstraintLayout и в нем ImageButton

Comment: Вот если Вы в вопрос добавите свою разметку - это будет намного эффективнее. А так попытки помочь Вам пытаясь представить что там у Вас в xml запилено - просто трата времени и тренировка фантазии.

Comment: @V.March обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример того как оставить Вашу кнопку размером `30dp*30dp`. И в то же время увеличить область клика на `16dp` с каждой стороны:

```
<ImageButton
android:contentDescription="@string/button_refresh"
android:layout_width="62dp"
android:layout_height="62dp"
android:padding="16dp"

android:background="@null"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_arrow"

/>
```

Параметры `layout_marginTop="0dp"` и `layout_marginEnd="0dp"`.

Обратите внимание что между вашей кнопкой и `TextView`который стоит слева от кнопки будет расстояние на `16dp` больше чем было изначально!

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" //Удалить параметр.
    android:fontFamily="@font/digital7"
    android:text="@string/numberOfTime_t1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/refresh"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/timer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Как вариант, придется убрать `layout_marginEnd="8dp"`. И все же, это уменьшит расстояние только на `8dp`. Это то, о чем я говорил в комментарии к Вашему вопросу, что нужно будет пожертвовать местом для того что бы расширить область клика.

Если Вам критично иметь визуальное расстояние в `8dp` между этими элементами, то придется поиграться с наложением виджетов. *Но это дурной тон, и Вы сами потом на этом будете спотыкаться.*

Проще будет уменьшить область клика слева до `8dp`. В таком случае получится что-то типа:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"

    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_arrow"

    />
```

PS.:
*Естественно размеры паддингов(увеличение области клика) - на Ваш вкус. В ответе я привел пример именно с `16dp` так как это не нарушит Вашу верстку сверху и справа, и минимально повлияет на нижний и левый край кнопки.*

Answer (score 0):

Как написал UjinUkr. Создайте контейнер для кнопки с размерами более чем кнопка. Установите ему параметр clickable = true. Создайте экземпляр контейнера в активити и назначьте на него листенер так же как и на кнопку. (На кнопку не требуется назначать листенер)

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="your_size"
android:layout_height="your_size"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```